# Ansible - cant start or stop service with right permission

Tags: ansible, systemd, systemctl

I have a weird issue where I cant start or stop a service using systemd module. I get the following error if I run the ansible task:

```
"Unable to stop service inubit.service: Failed to stop inubit.service: Connection timed out\nSee system logs and 'systemctl status inubit.service' for details."
```

The user "integration" that should run the task has the sudo permission. If I run the commands with integration user manually on the machine or use ansible command task, they work.

```
sudo systemctl start inubit.service
sudo systemctl stop inubit.service
```

/etc/sudoers:

```
integration ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl restart inubit
integration ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl start inubit
integration ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl stop inubit
integration ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl status inubit
integration ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl restart inubit.service
integration ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl start inubit.service
integration ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl stop inubit.service
integration ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl status inubit.service
```

The task:

```
- name: Stop inubit service if running
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: inubit.service
    state: stopped
  become: true
  become_user: integration
```

Comment: In Ansible, [privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general): _"You cannot limit privilege escalation permissions to certain commands. Ansible does not always use a specific command to do something but runs modules (code) from a temporary file name which changes every time. If you have ‘/sbin/service’ or ‘/bin/chmod’ as the allowed commands this will fail with Ansible as those paths won’t match with the temporary file that Ansible creates to run the module."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user 'integration' may indeed have the permissions to run commands via sudo, i.e. to run commands as another user, but the user itself may not have appropriate permissions to stop systemd services.

Your ansible task is equivalent to the command `sudo -u integration systemctl stop inubit.service` [1](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#using-become).

Try removing "become_user" or changing it to "become_user: root".

Comment: in /etc/sudoers i gave the required permissions to the integration user to start, stop etc. inubit service, if i use become_user: root it works, but i want to control the service with the integration user

Comment: @Dokksen Your sudoers file simply defines that the user integration may run the command with sudo without giving a password. The command is still run with the permissions of "root" and my answer stands. Is there a specific reason why you must use the "integration" user?

Comment: yeah I just understand you, thank you, we just wanted to minimize using the root user but we stiil need his root permissions indeed.